# How to unlock userLocks in EA repository

Tags: enterprise-architect

Currently we have a big number of userLocks in EA repository, which Im not able to unlock as administrator (with right "Security - Manage Locks"). Users who locked pakcages and elements do not working in company anymore.

Locks are available in t_seclocks and when I go to element and click on "Lock..." than I see "The selected element is user locked by person XY...". When I open GUI "Manage Locks" there are no userLocks available. When I try to use some standardized methods like .ReleaseUserLock() in script, it is not working as well.

I have tried to described problem [here](https://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,48068.0.html), but here I have problem a bit simplified and it is possibility a upload screen as well... [image: [Manage Locks]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to try is to run a **project integrity check**.
[image]

If that doesn't help you can delete the locks from the database using a script

```
Repository.Execute "delete from t_seclocks where userID = '<GUID of deleted user>'"
```

*Disclaimer: `Repository.Execute` is an undocumented and unsupported method. If you screw up your database you are completely on your own. Make sure to make a backup before trying anything.*

Comment: Super thanks! Problem was not in integrity, but I had a wrong statement with "repository.execute". Now delete statement is working without problem...